# Typo3 8.7.x / Extbase: Get selected categories of a content object

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-8.x

how to get the selected categories of the content element at my controller? I have an plugin where the editor have to select system categories, but I don't know how to get the selected uids/categories at my controller. The field categories of tt_content shows only the number of selected categories.

At the moment I'm using the following code at my controller, but I can't imagine there is now other (better) way:

```
    $uid = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data['uid'];

    $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('sys_category');
    $query = $queryBuilder->select('sys_category.uid', 'sys_category.title')->from('sys_category');
    $query->join(
        'sys_category',
        'sys_category_record_mm',
        'mm',
        $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('mm.uid_local', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('sys_category.uid')),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('mm.uid_foreign', $uid),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('mm.tablenames', $queryBuilder->quote('tt_content')),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('mm.fieldname', $queryBuilder->quote('categories'))
        )
    );

    $result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the categories using a model? If so, can you add the relevant parts from your model? If not, how are you trying to access the categories?

Comment: No I want to get the selected categories of the tt_content object (listType = my plugin)

Comment: Neither do we, because you didn't show us any code, input, expected output, actual output, error messages, or any log file warnings or notices etc. Update yoyur question!

Comment: Alright now we're getting nearer a question

Comment: sorry I just added my code. It's working, but I want to know, if there are a better way.